# RaceOnRCWCleanup when running console app for speech recognition

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I don't know either we can create a console app or not for speech recognition(searched for the same but didn't find any answer)and tried this code.

I have this code working in winforms app

but  when trying to create this app in console visual studio is giving a very strange error mscorelib.pdb not found.And transferring to a page mscorelib.pdb

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public  class Program
    {
        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            tester tst = new tester();
            tst.DoWorks();
           
        }

    }
    public class tester
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
        Choices clist = new Choices();

        public void DoWorks()
        {
            clist.Add(new string[] { "how are you", "what is the current time", "open chrome", "hello" });

            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(clist));

            sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            sre.LoadGrammar(gr);
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sre.SpeechRecognized += sre_recognised;
            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }

        public void sre_recognised(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text.ToString())
            {
                case "hello":ss.SpeakAsync("Hello shekar");
                    break;
                case "how are you": ss.SpeakAsync("I am fine and what about you");
                    break;
                case "what is the time":ss.SpeakAsync("current time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    break;
                case "open chrome":System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome", "wwe.google.com");
                    break;
                default:  ss.SpeakAsync("thank you");
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

here is the snapshot of the error page

[image]

I also loaded the given option "Microsoft.symbol.Server", but it is still giving the same output.

## EDIT

HERE is the output window

[image]

Outputs are of big lengths ,so not being able to show all the outputs ,captured some relevant parts (regret).

Comment: That’s not the actual error. That’s just a warning saying the debug data can’t be found. The actual exception is something different. Look at Output window and stack trace

Comment: Try decorating `Main` with attribute `[STAThread]`

Comment: @Crowcoder [STAThred] is also giving the same output.

Comment: You most probably will also have to prevent the Program from exiting prematurely. In a WinForms App you have this automatically. A Console Program will exit if you do not have some kind of loop or waithandle ...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen please review updated the output

Comment: As @Fildor said, prevent the app from exiting. What happens if you add a `Console.ReadLine()` statement after the call to `tst.DoWorks()`

Comment: @jeroenh its working, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the debugger issuing a [RaceOnRCWCleanup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/raceonrcwcleanup-mda). The reason may be that you are instantiating but not properly cleaning up COM objects created under the hood by `SpeechSynthesizer` and/or `SpeechRecognitionEngine`.

At the same time, a Console application is not automatically 'kept alive'. You need to specifically add code to prevent it from exiting immediately.

You need to do 2 things:

- Ensure your application stays alive long enough (for example, by adding a `Console.ReadLine()` statement in the `Main` method
- Make sure that resources are properly cleaned up. Both SpeechRecognitionEngine and SpeechSynthesizer implement `IDisposable`, so they should be disposed when no longer needed. To do this properly, implement `IDisposable` in your tester class:

Example:

```
 public class Tester 
 {
    SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    public void Dispose() 
    {
         ss.Dispose();
         sre.Dispose();
    }
 }
```